# OpenCSV defaults for escape char

Tags: java, opencsv

I've had a look at the latest version of OpenCSV. The escape char default seems to be different between the reader and writer, which doesn't really make sense to me.

Defaults:

```
Writer:
Seperator: ,
Quote char: "
Escape char: "
Line end: \n

Reader:
Seperator: ,
Quote char: "
Escape char: \
Strict quotes: false
Ignore leading whitespace: true
```

Have I read the defaults wrong, or is there an obvious reason why they are different that I am not seeing?

Comment: This is indeed rather odd. I can not see any reason for that default. The writer produces output that the reader can not correctly read.